# How do I get access to AWS Bucketobject in a AWS Lamda Extension?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, pulumi

I want to read a file stored in BucketObject in my code running on Lamda Exteions.
The Pulumi code for the Lamda Function with Lamda Extension looks like this:

```
import * as aws from "@pulumi/aws"
import * as pulumi from "@pulumi/pulumi";
import  {executionRole} from "./ExecutionRole"

const handler= "org.steinko.shortcode.LambdaHandler::handleRequest"


export const lamdaFunction = new aws.lambda.Function("lamda-function", {
    code: new pulumi.asset.FileArchive("../app/build/libs/shortcode-0.0.1-all.jar"),   
    runtime: aws.lambda.Runtime.Java11,
    handler: handler,
    role: executionRole.arn,
    name: "uppercase",
    memorySize: 300,
    timeout: 100,
    tracingConfig:{mode:"Active"},
    architectures:["arm64"],
    layers: [ "arn:aws:lambda:eu-north-1:901920570463:layer:aws-otel-java-agent-arm64-ver-1-24-0:1"], 
    environment: {
        variables: {
            AWS_LAMBDA_EXEC_WRAPPER: "/opt/otel-handler",
            OPENTELEMETRY_COLLECTOR_CONFIG_FILE: "https://steinko-config-collector.s3.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/collector.yaml", 
        }
            
        }
},
   )
```

Code for the Bucket, BucketObject and BucketObjectPolicy looks like this:

```
import * as aws from "@pulumi/aws";

export const configBucket = new aws.s3.BucketV2("config-bucket", {bucket: "steinko-config-collector"}


import * as pulumi from "@pulumi/pulumi";
import * as aws from "@pulumi/aws";
import {configBucket} from "./Bucket"

export const configBucketObkect = new aws.s3.BucketObjectv2("collector.yaml", {
    bucket: configBucket.id,
    source: new pulumi.asset.FileAsset("./lamda/collector.yaml"),
    acl: "public-read"
});


import * as aws from "@pulumi/aws";
import * as pulumi from "@pulumi/pulumi";
import {configBucket} from './Bucket'


const policyDocument = aws.iam.getPolicyDocumentOutput({
    statements: [{
        principals: [{
            type: "AWS",
            identifiers: ["888219289265"],
        }],
        actions: [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
                ],
        resources: [
          configBucket.arn,
            pulumi.interpolate`${configBucket.arn}/*`,
        ],
    }],
});

export const bucketPolicy = new aws.s3.BucketPolicy("bucketPolicy", {
    bucket: configBucket.id,
    policy: policyDocument.apply(policyDocument => policyDocument.json),
    })
```

When I execute a test on the deployed code I get a errormessage:

{
"level": "info",
"ts": 1686142124.2574954,
"msg": "done",
"error": "failed to get config: cannot resolve the configuration: cannot retrieve the configuration: failed to load resource from uri "https://steinko-config-collector.s3.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/collector.yaml". status code: 403; request failed with status 403 Forbidden",
"errorCauses": [
{
"error": "failed to get config: cannot resolve the configuration: cannot retrieve the configuration: failed to load resource from uri "https://steinko-config-collector.s3.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/collector.yaml". status code: 403"
},
{
"error": "request failed with status 403 Forbidden"
}
]
}

What must I do to get the file loaded into the code on the Lamda Extension?
);